# How is it possible that data in Kafka survives container recycling?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-streams

First, I do not know whether this issue is with Kafka or with Docker … I am a rookie regarding both topics. But I assume that it is more a Docker than a Kafka problem (in fact it will be my problem not really understanding one or the other …).

I installed Docker on a Raspberry 4 and created Docker images for Kafka and for Zookeeper; I had to create them by myself because 64-bit Raspi was not supported by any of the existing images (at least I could not find anyone). But I got them working.

Next I implemented the Kafka Streams example (Wordcount) from the Kafka documentation; it runs fine, counting the words in all the texts you push into it, keeping the numbers from all previous runs. That is somehow expected; at least it is described that way in that documentation.

So after some test runs I wanted to reset the whole thing.

I thought the easiest way to get there is to shut down the docker containers, delete the mounted folders on the host and start over.

But that does not work: the word counters are still there! Meaning the word count did not start from 0 …

Ok, next turn: not only removing the containers, but rebuild the images, too! Both, Zookeeper and Kafka, of course!

No difference! The word count from all the previous runs were retained.

Using `docker system prune --volumes` made no difference also …

From my limited understanding of Docker, I assumed that any runtime data is stored in the container, or in the mounted folders (volumes). So when I delete the containers and the folders on the Docker host that were mounted by the containers, I expect that any status would have gone.

Obviously not … so I missed something important here, most probably with Docker.

The docker-compose file I used:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: tquadrat/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /data/zookeeper/config:/config
      - /data/zookeeper/data:/data
      - /data/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
      - /data/zookeeper/logs:/logs
    environment:
      ZOO_SERVERS: "server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888;2181"
    restart: always

  kafka:
    image: tquadrat/kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    volumes:
      - /data/kafka/config:/config
      - /data/kafka/logs:/logs
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka:29091,EXTERNAL://:9091"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka:29091,EXTERNAL://TCON-PI4003:9091"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
    restart: always
```

The script file I used to clear out the mounted folders:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eux

DATA="/data"
KAFKA_DATA="$DATA/kafka"
ZOOKEEPER_DATA="$DATA/zookeeper"

sudo rm -R "$KAFKA_DATA"
sudo rm -R "$ZOOKEEPER_DATA"

mkdir -p "$KAFKA_DATA/config" "$KAFKA_DATA/logs"
mkdir -p "$ZOOKEEPER_DATA/config" "$ZOOKEEPER_DATA/data" "$ZOOKEEPER_DATA/datalog" "$ZOOKEEPER_DATA/logs"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your kafka and zookeeper images configured to use the paths that you've mounted as volumes? How are you destroying and restarting your containers?

Comment: Yes, they are configured to use the paths, and when I looked to these locations, both Kafka and Zookeeper have written something there. To destroy the container, I usually use just `docker-compose down` and `docker ps -a` does not show them any longer … I also tried `docker system prune --volumes` … of course I have to run my `cleanup.sh` script, too.

Comment: You really shouldn't mount config. Let the environment variables set the configs

Comment: As said, I am new to Docker, and my Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yaml are based on what I found on DockerHub and github (to avoid "copied from"). But I found the mounted config dirs extremely useful to verify the configuration, as the base images I started with did not have a shell (something I changed in the meantime). But could this be relevant for my problem?

Comment: Not necessarily, but the files would be overwritten on each container restart, if you did decide to edit them on the host. And I would be surprised if you could not `docker-compose exec kafka cat /config/server.properties`, or use grep`... Containers *need* a shell to run the Kafka scripts.

Comment: @cricket_007: "Containers *need* a shell to run […] scripts" – Yepp, but not necessarily `/bin/bash` … and I completely forgot (ignored? blocked out?) that `/bin/sh` is a valid shell, too. So my attempts using `docker exec -it kafka /bin/bash` failed until I added it to the Docker file … although `docker exec -it kafka /bin/sh` would have done the job …

Comment: The Bourne shell is separate from the posix shell, yes. But the container still has **a** shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams stores its own state under the `"state.dir"` config on the Host machine its running on. In Apache Kafka libraries, this is under `/tmp`. First check if you have overridden that property in your code.

As far as Docker goes, try without volumes first.

> Using docker system prune --volumes made no difference also …

That would clean unattached volumes made with `docker volume create` or `volumes:` in Compose, not host-mounted directories.

Comment: You explicitly mention Kafka Streams, and it that stores its own state on the Host machine its running on. In my case, the Kafka Streams processor is running on another machine than Docker (and the Kafka server inside that Docker), but on that machine, I could not find any traces from Kafka in the `/tmp`.

Comment: In Confluent libraries, its `/var/lib/kafka-streams`... https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#optional-configuration-parameters

Comment: Yeah, after your hint with `state.dir`, I found that page, too. But on my workstation (where I run the Streams processor), that folder is not writeable for me, and I have no clue, where Docker placed it alternatively. But after setting the config explicitly (and removing its contents after a run) I now can reset the Streams processor.

Comment: If the client code is not running in a container, then Docker is not controlling that directory

Answer (score 1):

As I assumed right from the beginning, the problem was mainly my lack of knowledge.

The behaviour I observed is *not* related to a magical data store for Docker that survives all attempts to kill it; it is not related to Docker at all.

I use those Docker images to run Zookeeper and the Kafka server on it. Then I switched back to my workstation machine, wrote that code (the "Wordcount" sample) that implements a Kafka Stream processor. When I started that in my IDE, it was executed on my local machine, accessing Kafka over the network.

My assumption was that *any* state was stored on the Kafka server, so that dumping that should reset the whole thing; as that does not work, I dumped also the Zookeeper, and as this was to no avail also, I removed nearly everything …

After some hints here I found that Kafka Streams processors maintain their own local state in a filesystem folder that is configured through `state.dir` (`StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG`) – see [Configuring a Streams Application](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html). This means that a Kafka Streams processor maintains its *own local* state *independent* from any Kafka server, and – as in my case when it runs on my local machine – also outside/unrelated to any Docker container …

According to the documentation, the default location should be `/var/lib/kafka-streams`, but this is not writeable in my environment – no idea where the Stream processor put its state instead.

After setting the configuration value `state.dir` for my Streams processor explicitly to a folder in my home directory, I could see that state on my disk, and after removing that, the word count started over with one.

A deeper look into the documentation for Kafka Streams revealed that I could have got the same with a call to `KafkaStream.cleanup()` before starting or after closing the stream processor (no removing files on the filesystem required).

Comment: Note: that link is only valid if you pull kafka-streams dependency from Confluent repo, not Maven Central

Comment: @cricket_007: Sorry, but which link are you referring to?

Comment: The one link in your answer

Comment: @cricket_007: Then you mean that the information provided through that link is only valid when the kafka-streams dependency is pulled from the Confluent repository, and not that the link as such is broken … Nevertheless, I used the Maven Central stuff, and the configuration I created based on the linked document worked for me. Seems that I did not hit the critical points yet.

Comment: I mean the properties provided in the table by the link, yes, as compared to https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html